# getcifsacl does not work with CIFS mount versions 2 or 3

Tags: mount, access-control-list, cifs

When I mount CIFS share with `vers=1.0` I can perform `getcifsacl` sucessfully.

```
# mount -t cifs //example.com/Users/milo /mnt/cifs -o vers=1.0
# getcifsacl /mnt/cifs/file.png

REVISION:0x1
CONTROL:0x8504
OWNER:S-1-5-21-1111111111-222222222-33333333-11824
GROUP:S-1-5-21-1111111111-222222222-33333333-513
ACL:S-1-5-21-1111111111-222222222-33333333-11824:ALLOWED/I/FULL
ACL:S-1-5-21-1111111111-222222222-33333333-3200:ALLOWED/I/FULL
ACL:NT Authority\SYSTEM:ALLOWED/I/FULL
```

But when I mount with `vers=2.0`, or `2.1`, or `3.0`, ACL reading fails.

```
getxattr error: 95
REVISION:0x0
CONTROL:0x0
```

OS is Debian Stretch (9.6), cifs-utils package 2:6.7-1. CIFS share is from Nettapp data store. Mounts from Windows XP, 8, 10 works fine.

Why `getcifsacl` depends on SMB protocol version? Can I read ACL via newer SMB protocol?

Answer (score 0):

To get it work, one need newer kernel and newer cifs-utils.

Reading an ACL by `getcifsacl` and setting it by `setcifsacl` with mount versions 2.0, 2.1 or 3.0 works well with kernel `4.19.0-0.bpo.1-amd64` (backport for Debian Strech) and cifs-utils version `cifs-utils-6.8` (git tag). All utils work with kernel 4.20.4 too.

I received solution hints in samba-technical mailing list: https://lists.samba.org/archive/samba-technical/2019-January/132176.html